# C++ Call function pointer from multiple different Classes

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, methods

x

Hello,

i want to make a function call pointer in my GUI Button Class which
is so flexible that i can call a function from multiple different classes:

```
class A
{
    void funcTestA();
};
class B
{
    void funcTestB();
};
class X
{
    void (*_callback)(int); //In one X object is the funcTestA() pointer saved and in another X object the funcTestB() pointer
    void callThem();
};
void X::callThem()
{
    this->_callback();
}
```

It gave me an error that i need something similar like this:

```
void (A::*)()
```

or:

```
void (B::*)()
```

But i want that can use dynamically either the funcTestA pointer or the funcTestB pointer.

Is this even possible?

**EDIT:**

Ok i know that i need a reference Object to call the function like this:

```
A* pA;
(pA->callback)();
```

But if i try to use the pointer var like this:

```
(A::*callback)();
```

I become an

> expected id-expression before '*' token

Error?

**BAD SOLUTION:**

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Use a typedef instead:

```
typedef  void (A::*aMemberFunctionPointer)();
aMemberFunctionPointer _callback = NULL;
```

**Look for Thomas answer for a better solution.**

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Function pointers to class methods need to be made aware of the implied  `this` parameter. Give this a read for details: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks that helps me a lot but why get do i get an error if i use (A::*callback)(); ? The name of this pointer must be written behind * or am i wrong?

Comment: If you want a flexible callback type with a specific signature, use `std::function` or something similar. Function pointers *do not* work the way you're trying to make them work. *Member*-function pointers will do what you want, sort of, and with additional limitations, but there's really no reason to use something so primitive when `std::function` exists (and if you're using an old toolchain that doesn't support the C++11 standard library there's `boost::function` and various other implementations of the same concept).

Comment: As for your question about the specific syntax error you're seeing, note that the FAQ page linked by user4581301 includes multiple sections on syntax, all of which amount to "the syntax for member function pointers is too complicated to use in its raw form."

Comment: @KyleStrand Yes sorry just found it and now it works with typedef. And i will give a std::function a try thank you.

Comment: @KyleStrand has the right of it. [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and the rest of the [functional library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) make the whole problem go away. You might also want to look up functors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i want that can use dynamically either the funcTestA pointer or the funcTestB pointer.
>
> Is this even possible?

You can use std::function to store the callbacks and lambdas to bind to the instances. See [live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/640527a3835aa5f8).

You will have to ensure that the instances used in the callbacks are still valid when the callbacks are invoked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    void funcTestA() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};
struct B
{
    void funcTestB()  { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

struct X
{
    void setCallback( std::function<void(void)> callback ){ _callback = callback; }
    void callThem() { _callback(); } 

    std::function<void(void)> _callback;
};


int main()
{
    X xa;
    X xb;
    
    {
         A a;
         B b;
    
         xa.setCallback( [&](){ a.funcTestA(); } );
         xb.setCallback( [&](){ b.funcTestB(); } );
    
         // callbacks ok
         xa.callThem();
         xb.callThem();
    }
    // here callbacks undefined as A and B are destroyed
}
```